# Using awk sed et al. to parse fields from a file having no end tags

Tags: parsing, text, awk, sed, delimited

My desired output is a comma-delimited file.  If all else fails, I know that I can write a script with for/each logic or something, but I am hoping for an elegant solution using awk and sed, which have served me well so many times before.  I'm just stumped with this one.

Below is a representation of the data, followed by the desired outcome.   Note: each GROUPNUMBER has an associated set of GROUPMEMBER, GROUPMEMBERID, and MEMBERRANK fields (which are not always positioned at the first character of a line as they are in the sample data).  Other lines and text surrounding the GROUPNUMBER are unimportant, may also have colons, and are represented here as lorem ipsum text.  Some GROUPNUMBERs have no associated fields at all (as seen in the sample data in the final lines, for Group#88888). Also, in the sample data, GROUPNUMBER sections are shown as being separated with blank lines, but that is not always the case (sometimes the next section runs into the previous with no line break).

Sample data:

```
loremipsum: loremipsum?# loremipsum/123: loremipsumxx GROUPNUMBER:111222
loremipsum123:loremispum loremipsumxxxx
GROUPMEMBER:Joe:MEMBERRANK:1
GROUPMEMBERID:1234
GROUPMEMBER:Mike:MEMBERRANK:1
GROUPMEMBERID:2234
loremipsum14e3:loremispum loremipsumxxxx
loremipsum1eer534:loremispum loremipsumxxfgt
GROUPMEMBER:Sue:MEMBERRANK:89
GROUPMEMBERID:3234
GROUPMEMBER:John:MEMBERRANK:323
GROUPMEMBERID:4234:loremipsumaaa_loremipsum

loremipsum: loremipsum..<?# loremipsum/123: loremipsumxx GROUPNUMBER:333444
loremipsum123:loremispum loremipsumxxxx
GROUPMEMBER:Frank:MEMBERRANK:4
GROUPMEMBERID:5234
GROUPMEMBER:Laurie:MEMBERRANK:4
GROUPMEMBERID:6234

loremipsum: loremipsum..<?# loremipsum/123: loremipsumxx GROUPNUMBER:88888
loremipsum123:loremispum loremipsumxxxx
```

Desired output:

```
GROUPNUMBER, MEMBERNAME, MEMBERID, MEMBERRANK

Example from above data:
111222,Joe,1234,1
111222,Mike,2234,1
111222,Sue,3234,89
111222,John,4234,323
333444,Frank,5234,4
333444,Laurie,6234,4
88888,,,
```

Comment: `which have served me well so many times before` On this forum we encourage others to post what they have tried. Please kindly post what have you tried and show what is stopping you from writing it. What exactly is your question? While I believe it could be done in sed, an awk solution would be much easier and more readable.

Comment: [edit] your question to explain how to identify `GROUPNUMBER:111222`, etc. strings from all the rest of the text that you've loremipsum-ed. For example is that the only strings in your input that are `all upper case then colon then digits`?

Comment: `<input sed 's/GROUPNUMBER:/\n&/g;s/GROUPMEMBER:/\n&/g;s/GROUPMEMBERID:/\n&/g;s/MEMBERRANK/\n&/g' | awk -v OFS=, -F: 'function o(v){if(v){print n,m,i,r;p=m=i=r=""}}$1=="GROUPNUMBER"{o(p);n=$2;p=1}$1=="GROUPMEMBER"{o(m);m=$2}$1=="GROUPMEMBERID"{o(i);i=$2}$1=="MEMBERRANK"{o(r);r=$2}n&&m&&i&&r{o(1)}END{o(p)}'`

Answer (score 2):

Might be barely possible in GNU sed... but it would be better to use something with a hashtable, or at least more variables than the hold space:

`sed -nE '/GROUPNUMBER:/{s/.*://;h};/GROUPMEMBER:/{N;G;s/GROUPMEMBER:(.*):MEMBERRANK:(.*)\nGROUPMEMBERID:([^:]*).*\n(.*)/\4,\1,\2,\3/p};${g;s/$/,,,/p}' file`

This is a hackish handling of the final group... the final line will always be the final groupnumber and three commas.

The gist:

- `sed -nE` to print only when specified, and to allow no-backslash capture groups
- `h` to hold the GROUPNUMBER
- `N;G` on the GROUPMEMBER lines to append the subsequent line and the groupnumber
- Capture groups 1-4 reordered to format the output
- The hack on `$`, the final line, which uses `g` to get the last GROUPNUMBER and print it with three commas

Answer (score 2):

It's not particularly easy, but neither is it incredibly difficult.  All the interesting information is in fields delimited by colons, so one part is to have `awk` split the input line into fields based on colons (`-F:`).  There's then a requirement to recognize group numbers, group members, member ranks, and member IDs. Any line with no matching information is simply ignored.  Finding the field values can be done by scanning through the fields looking for matches to the keyword, and returning the field after it as the value.  In the code below, the function `extractor` does that job.  It's also necessary to keep track of how many times a group number has been printed.  At the end of the input, or when a new group number is recognized, if the old group number has been printed zero times, then the group information needs to be printed.  The function `print_member` prints a member; it saves writing out the `printf` statement 3 times.

```
awk -F: '
function extractor(tag,   i)
{
    for (i = 1; i < NF; i++)
        if ($i ~ tag)
            return $(i + 1)
    return ""
}
function print_member()
{
    printf "%s,%s,%s,%s\n", groupnumber, groupmember, groupmemberid, memberrank
}
    /GROUPNUMBER:[0-9]+/ {
        if (groupnumber != "" && groupcount == 0)
            print_member()
        groupnumber = extractor("GROUPNUMBER")
        groupmember = ""
        memberrank = ""
        groupmemberid = ""
        groupcount = 0
    }
    /GROUPMEMBER:[^:]+:MEMBERRANK:[0-9]+/ {
        groupmember = extractor("GROUPMEMBER")
        memberrank = extractor("MEMBERRANK")
    }
    /GROUPMEMBERID:[0-9]+/ {
        groupmemberid = extractor("GROUPMEMBERID")
        print_member()
        groupcount++
    }
    END {
        if (groupcount == 0)
            print_member()
    }' data
```

Given the data file in the question (name `data`), the output is:

```
111222,Joe,1234,1
111222,Mike,2234,1
111222,Sue,3234,89
111222,John,4234,323
333444,Frank,5234,4
333444,Laurie,6234,4
88888,,,
```

That seems to be the required output.  Now consider an altered input file (with numerous additions) like this:

```
loremipsum: loremipsum?# loremipsum/123: loremipsumxx GROUPNUMBER:111222:hydrangea
loremipsum123:loremispum loremipsumxxxx
GROUPMEMBER:Joe:MEMBERRANK:1:orchid
GROUPMEMBERID:1234
GROUPMEMBER:Mike:piscatore:MEMBERRANK:1
GROUPMEMBERID:2234
loremipsum14e3:loremispum loremipsumxxxx
loremipsum1eer534:loremispum loremipsumxxfgt
GROUPMEMBER:Sue:MEMBERRANK:89
GROUPMEMBERID:3234
GROUPMEMBER:John:MEMBERRANK:323
GROUPMEMBERID:4234:loremipsumaaa_loremipsum
loremipsum: loremipsum..<?# loremipsum/123: loremipsumxx GROUPNUMBER:333444
loremipsum123:loremispum loremipsumxxxx
GROUPMEMBER:Frank:MEMBERRANK:4
GROUPMEMBERID:5234
GROUPMEMBER:Laurie:MEMBERRANK:4
GROUPMEMBERID:6234
loremipsum: loremipsum..<?# loremipsum/123: loremipsumxx GROUPNUMBER:88888
loremipsum123:loremispum loremipsumxxxx
loremipsum: loremipsum..<?# loremipsum/123: loremipsumxx GROUPNUMBER:222444
loremipsum123:loremispum loremipsumxxxx
GROUPMEMBER:Helen Mary Ann:MEMBERRANK:1
loremipsum: loremipsum..<?# loremipsum/123: loremipsumxx GROUPNUMBER:222555
loremipsum123:loremispum loremipsumxxxx
loremipsum123:loremispum loremipsumxxxx
```

The output is now:

```
111222,Joe,1234,1
111222,Joe,2234,1
111222,Sue,3234,89
111222,John,4234,323
333444,Frank,5234,4
333444,Laurie,6234,4
88888,,,
222444,Helen Mary Ann,,1
222555,,,
```

This looks reasonable.  The spaces in Helen Mary Ann's name don't matter; there was no member ID for her.  The group in the middle with no information shows up correctly too.

Clearly, you can convert this into a usable shell script by putting it into a file and replacing `data` with `"$@"` so that it will process the file names given on the command line, or will read standard input if there are no such names.

---

As noted in the comments, the code above assumes that the GROUPMEMBER and MEMBERRANK fields will be consecutive on a line, without any of the random-ish 'ipsum lorem' type fields in between.  If in fact there can be an 'ipsum lorem' field in between (I used `piscatore` in my second data set), then the script needs to be revised to identify GROUPMEMBER and MEMBERRANK separately.  This has the additional advantage that if the input contained:

```
ipsum lorem:MEMBERRANK:1:ipsum lorem:GROUPMEMBER:Hailey:ipsum lorem
```

or

```
ipsum lorem:MEMBERRANK:110:ipsum lorem
hallucination:GROUPMEMBER:Julian:doldrums
```

then it would recognize the information accurately (with the lines in either order in the second example).  The GROUPMEMBERID must be the last of the three entries for each member with a given GROUPNUMBER.

```
awk -F: '
function extractor(tag,   i)
{
    for (i = 1; i < NF; i++)
        if ($i ~ tag)
            return $(i + 1)
    return ""
}
function print_member()
{
    printf "%s,%s,%s,%s\n", groupnumber, groupmember, groupmemberid, memberrank
}
    /GROUPNUMBER:[0-9]+/ {
        if (groupnumber != "" && groupcount == 0)
            print_member()
        groupnumber = extractor("GROUPNUMBER")
        groupmember = ""
        memberrank = ""
        groupmemberid = ""
        groupcount = 0
    }
    /GROUPMEMBER:[^:]+/ {
        groupmember = extractor("GROUPMEMBER")
    }
    /MEMBERRANK:[0-9]+/ {
        memberrank = extractor("MEMBERRANK")
    }
    /GROUPMEMBERID:[0-9]+/ {
        groupmemberid = extractor("GROUPMEMBERID")
        print_member()
        groupcount++
    }
    END {
        if (groupcount == 0)
            print_member()
    }' data
```

The output is now:

```
111222,Joe,1234,1
111222,Mike,2234,1
111222,Sue,3234,89
111222,John,4234,323
333444,Frank,5234,4
333444,Laurie,6234,4
88888,,,
222444,Helen Mary Ann,,1
222555,,,
```

Comment: this breaks if GROUPNUMBER follows GROUPMEMBER, GROUPMEMBERID or MEMBERRANK on a single line

Comment: @jhnc — If the data in the example is not reasonably fully illustrative of what can happen, then yes, the processing might need to change.  The example data clearly shows that GROUPNUMBER only appears on a line without any of the other items.  If that is not accurate on the complete data set, it needs to be shown in the question.  We need only address what the question shows, or what can be inferred.

Comment: final line of question mentions that sections may follow on with no linebreak

Comment: @jhnc: Since the preamble to that says "in the sample data, GROUPNUMBER sections are shown as being separated with blank lines, but that is not always the case", I interpret that to mean that the blank lines (aka 'line break') are not always present, as shown in my second data file.  If the 'line break' is really meant to be 'newline' — a possible but not necessarily plausible interpretation — then yes, more work would be needed.  YMMV.  Until and unless the OP suggests that the line break referred to is 'newline' not 'blank line', I'm not going to fret.

Comment: it was hard explaining this clearly, sorry for the confusion. There is a newline after each row.   I was saying that extra blank lines (double newlines?) seen in the sample data are not always there, sometimes it looks like Jonathan's data. I mentioned this because I can't rely on  "double newline" to indicate the end of Group.  Using functions is sort of like writing a script, but having them inside a single awk command is just so cool.  can't wait to try this at work tomorrow.  one thing though, the second line of your final output shows "Joe"but it should be "Mike", is that a mistype?

Comment: @Jason908 — It's a bug, caused by introducing `:piscatore:` between `GROUPMEMBER:Mike` and `MEMBERRANK:1`. There are 2 possibilities. One is that you'd never find a 'lorem ipsum' field (or `piscatore`) between GROUPMEMBER and MEMBERANK; the other is that you could.  If there can never be a value where I put `piscatore`, then GIGO (garbage in, garbage out).  If you can have a field there, then the conditions on GROUPMEMBER and MEMBERRANK need to be separated. It's more mechanical than hard. Which way should I go? I suspect that allowing an 'ipsum lorem' field there is appropriate. Your call?

Comment: Fortunately there will never be a field between GROUPMEMBER and MEMBERRANK.  If anything, MEMBERRANK could not appear at all, but there won't be anything between the two like "piscatore"

Comment: fyi It's not working for me, I only get the first GROUPMEMBER.  I'm working on it... (GNU awk 4.1.4)

Comment: Curious!!  I just tested with GNU Awk 4.1.3 on three data files I've got, and both scripts produce the expected results for me (the results shown above for the data shown), and the same results as the macOS (BSD) Awk does.  That they produce the same result doesn't surprise me; I'm not doing anything tricky or that exploits features of a specific version of Awk.  So, did you copy'n'paste or did you retype?